# r.table('table').filter({thing : 'thing'}).run(conn, function(err, result) {}) returning undefined

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

So I,m trying to filter my database for names with this code:

```
r.table('Profiles').filter({mcname : user}).run(connection, function (err, profiles) {
                            console.log(r.table("Profiles").filter({mcname : user}).toString())
                            if (profiles.length == 0 || profiles == null) {
                                message.channel.send('No one was found by this name!')
                            } else if (profiles.length == 1) {
                                message.channel.send(`**${profiles[0].mcname}** is the IGN of **${profiles[0].name}!**`)
                            } else {
                                for (let i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
                                    embed.setTitle(`Here are the users I found with that IGN! Total(${profiles.length})`)
                                    embed.addField(profiles[i].name, profiles[i].mcname)
                                }
                                message.channel.send(embed)
                            }
                        })
```

But it does not return any results.

I was expecting an array because that is what it returns in the database explorer, but treating it like an array just returns undefined, and printing it raw shows the connection info.

Any way to see the results and not connection info, or just print them to an array if it does not already?

Answer (score 0):

`r.table('Profiles').filter({mcname : user})` will return you a cursor.

If you want an array, you have to use `.coerceTo('array')`:

```
r.table('Profiles').filter({mcname : user}).coerceTo('array').run(...)
```

https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/coerce_to/